# Sizing/stretching images to dimensions known only after page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

On my website, users can upload large images. I display these images like this:

```
<img id="userImage" src="userImage.ashx?width=740&id=4fc265d4-a83c-4069-8d6d-0fc78ae2840d">
```

userImage.ashx is a handler that returns image files based on id, so in this example the image for user `4fc265d4-a83c-4069-8d6d-0fc78ae2840d` is returned. You can also set other attributes - in this example only `width` is given. The image is resized so that it is 740px wide.

I set the `src` of the image in javascript, once the rest of the page has loaded. By doing this I know how wide the image has to be to fill all the available space:

```
var width = document.getElementById("userImageHolder").getComputedSize().width;
document.getElementById("userImage").src = "flash/userImage.ashx?type=micrositePhoto&id=" + userId + "&width=" + width;
```

This all works, but the image doesn't load until everything else on the page has loaded. I have a complex solution to a simple problem.

Is there a better way to do this? What is the best way to shrink/stretch images to fill an area that is only known once the page loads?

Comment: maybe you can load an image that is roughly the size you want and scale it with javascript by changing the image tags height/width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out what the upper limit is for width and height and generate the image to that size, then use `max-width/max-height` to allow the browser to auto scale it based on the size of the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Try to preload your images in a `onDOMReady` handler, and then insert in an `onLoad` one. While this can't guarantee the images to be loaded *before* everything else, they can at least start loading earlier.

Someting like this (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var imageArray = [],
  imageSrc = [];

//Fill image src array from somewhere

  var len = imageSrc.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageSrc[i];

    img.onload = function(){
      //Do something with your loaded image
      imageArray.push(this);
    }
  }
});
```